# Sequential idempotence

Tags: dc.distributed-comp

I want to coalesce multiple operations in a system into one and am currently studying under what conditions it is admissible. The conditions that are needed are stronger than idempotence and I'm wondering if it has well-known name:

E.g.: considers two operations assigning a variable `A: x ← 1` and `B: x ← 2`. Both are idempotent.

By idempotence, we can conclude various things about sequential composition of those operations:

```
A * A = A
A * A * B * B = A * B
```

But we cannot use idempotence to get `A * B = B` even though that's of course true given the definitions of `A` and `B`.

How would you name or concisely describe this compositional property of the operations?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit like [absorption](https://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Absorption_(mathematics)).  But I'm not quite sure this is exactly what you need.